# angularJS $routeProvider

Tags: angularjs, grails

I am using angularJS in my grails application. Before that, i tried a sample from internet. I tried to use angularJS $routeProvider for the partial views in my main view. My workflows are as follows:

my main view is index.gsp:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>AngularJS Routing example</title>
</head>

<body ng-app="routeApplication">

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <ul class="nav">
                <li><a href="#AddNewOrder"> Add </a></li>
                <li><a href="#ShowOrders"> Show </a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <div ng-view></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<script src="js/angular.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

My partial views are: add_order.gsp and show_orders.gsp to show a sample message for each view.

my app.js is as follows:

```
var sampleApp = angular.module('routeApplication', ['ngRoute']);

sampleApp.config(['$routeProvider',
    function($routeProvider) {
        var base = '${request.contextPath}';

        $routeProvider.
            when('/AddNewOrder', {
            templateUrl: 'templates/add_order.html',
            controller: 'AddOrderController'
        }).
            when('/ShowOrders', {
                templateUrl: 'templates/show_orders.gsp',
                controller: 'ShowOrdersController'
            }).
            otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/AddNewOrder'
            });
    }]);


sampleApp.controller('AddOrderController', function($scope) {
    $scope.message = 'This is Add new order screen';

});


sampleApp.controller('ShowOrdersController', function($scope) {
    $scope.message = 'This is Show orders screen';

});
```

Note: i created a templates folder and placed my parital views on that.

This problem is that, whenever i click to load my partial views it shows

```
 `http://localhost/angularJSrouting/templates/show_orders.gsp`
    404 Not Found
```

Am i missing something or is there any problem of placing the partial views?

Comment: finally worked, template folder should be placed inside webapp. in case of html extension of a file it works as the file name. but in case of gsp it needs to add an underscore and surprisingly after adding a 's' like plural form. in case of gsp: file name _show_orders.gsp and templateUrl templates/_show_orders.gsp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this will work. Since your templateUrl is templates/show_orders.gsp angularjs will try to find that file inside templates folder in your webapp.

Comment: thanks for your reply Rishi Saraf. I also placed my views in webapp inside templates folder, but it did not work also. i became puzzled!!.

Answer (score 0):

You have to redirect to

```
  http://localhost/#/angularJSrouting/templates/show_orders.gsp url
```

can you use '/' instead of '#' in those html line

```
 <li><a href="#AddNewOrder"> Add </a></li>
 <li><a href="#ShowOrders"> Show </a></li>
```

Comment: '/' does not work. i have tried redirection like you said but in vain.